# Attaching messages to Safe generated transactions

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am trying to send some messages on an EVM network. Can I put an arbitrary human-readable message (UTF-8) in the hex data of a transaction originating from a multi-sig?
AFAIK I cannot send such messages to smart contract addresses. Can I create those, though?

For example, this transaction - the input data in UTF-8 reads as "Is this possible from a safe?" how do I send such messages from a Safe, if it's possible? :
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x3d76d471600f49e5f86ba0b0928fafa91c2e3951e2fb18927dc217235832b915

Comment: Do you know how to write custom scripts? If you can then you can probably do it by writing a script that will interact with the Safe API.